# Is the Quran uncreated? (Majority opinion)

Tags: quran, creation, aqidah, divine-attributes

Selam aleikum,

Is the Quran the uncreated and eternal word of God as Ahmad ibn Hanbal believed?

A short answer would be enough. I only want to know whether this view is the majority opinion of scholars or not. (Sunni View)

Thanks for responses.

Comment: A quick response is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some nuances when going in depth, however in general this is the standard creed of the Ahl al-Sunnah - not just Ahmad ibn Hanbal - that the Quran is the speech of Allah and being His attribute it is not created.

You may find this in books on aqeedah such as:

> وإن القرآن كلام الله، منه بدا بلا كيفية قولا، وأنزله على رسوله وحيا، وصدقه المؤمنون على ذلك حقا، وأيقنوا أنه كلام الله تعالى بالحقيقة، ليس بمخلوق ككلام البرية
>
> <sup>—  [Aqeedah al-Tahhaawiyyah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31610/165)</sup>

> القرآن كلام الله عز وجل، وكلام الله صفة من صفات ذاته، ولا يجوز أن يكون شيء من صفات ذاته مخلوقا ولا محدثا ولا حادثا
>
> <sup>—  [al-Itiqad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12997/55)</sup>

> القرآن كلام الله  ... منزل غير مخلوق
>
> <sup>— [Luma'tul Itiqad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/30855/13)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The Qu'ran is uncreated as every attribute of Allah is uncreated, eternal and has no beginning, and it would include this attribute. The Qu'ran being uncreated means that He spoke the word, which Jibraeel (a.s) heard from Him and bought down to the Prophet (s.a.w) and conveyed to him.

Abu ‘Abdullah ibn Ismaa‘eel said: I heard ‘Ubaydullah ibn Sa‘eed say: I heard Yahya ibn Sa‘eed say: I always heard our companions say that people’s deeds are created.

Abu ‘Abdullah said: Their movements, voices, actions and writing are created. As for the Qur’an that is recited, recorded in the Mus-haf, written, and memorised in people’s hearts, it is the word of Allah and is not created.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibadi_Islam

In Ibadi islam,

The Quran is created.
(My opinion, they mean it is Allah words. But it is not the only words, Allah has revelead to us some of his knowledge).  Allah knows better, I might be mistaken.

Other things Ibadi islam has a view on are:

2. Not seeing Allah in the Hereafter for the believers. Other sects believe in seeing.
   (My opinion, Allah is Allah wether in this life or Hereafter, he is alls creations Lord in all time and space, so nothing changes about Him, you don't see him, neither in the Hereafter). Some argue that seeing the Noor (the Light). Allah knows better, I might be mistaken.
3. Eternity in hellfire for the disobedient. Ibadi believe, this life is your test, in total, you do good, you are rewarded Heaven eternally, in total, you do bad and insist, Hell will be punishment eternally.  Allah knows better, I might be mistaken.

These things require all sects to put their reasons for their conclusions, their logical arguments for people to think about. At the end, we all believe Allah is the only god and believe in his (revealed) names (https://99namesofallah.name/)

Allah knows everything and we people know little.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the Quran is uncreated.

The predecessors unanimously agreed that whoever says that the Qur’an is created has become an infidel (kafir كافر).

So you must be careful.

"قال شيخ الإسلام ابن تيمية حاكياً عن السلف: ولهذا كفروا من يقول إن القرآن مخلوق وإن الله لا يرى في الآخرة. انتهى من مجموع الفتاوى."