# Is the Quran created or uncreated?

Tags: quran

I know there are similar questions here but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer anywhere to this simple question. Please send me a link if there exists a similar question.

Quran is an eternal word of God which is uncreated, that I know but, For example, if a non-Muslim burns a copy of the Quran, he has burnt the Quran itself or a copy of the Quran composed of pages & letters written via pen/ink?

How is the majority opinion that Quran is uncreated even in books according to the answers [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/63358/is-the-quran-uncreated-majority-opinion) ??

Comment: You can't burn the qur'an as the qur'an is the orally transmitted word of Allah- What you find between two bookshelves is not the qur'an, but a Moshaf. And you will find plenty of answers saying so.

Comment: Your question should eb is the Moshaf created or uncreated?

Comment: @Medi1Saif "You can't burn the qur'an as the qur'an is the orally transmitted word of Allah"... When a Hafidh is gone from this world, does that mean the Quran is also gone with him/her or it still remains ??

Comment: @Ghz... what logic is that? Of course the qur'an will remain.

Comment: @Medi1Saif What do you mean when you say "Quran is the orally transmitted word of Allah" and "What you find between two bookshelves is not the Quran but a Moshaf" ?

Comment: @Ghz... I'm pointing at a common mistake. People think that the book they hold in hands is the qur'an, while it is a moshaf a written or printed copy of the qur'an. As the qur'an is the word of Allah which ever since was transmitted orally from generation to generation.

Answer (score 1):

Qur'an itself is not created; it is the words that Allah had spoken. Perhaps this idea started from the Mushaf being something solid and toucheable.
I might find the link where I learned this but I don't promis anything. It's very reliable but i dont know where it is. if i find it i will send it here.
Salam Alaykom

Answer (score 1):

The Quran, as in the words of Allah, are not created.

As for the paper and ink, they are created. The voice of a person that is reciting is created.

But, what is written and what is recited are the words of God which are uncreated.

If a non-Muslim burns a book, he burns a book. But, the Quran still exists.

Comment: "If a non-Muslim burns a book (Quranic Mushaf), he burns a book. But, the Quran still exists.". So, the Quran which we read in Mushafs is not the real Quran?

Comment: If he burns a book, he is not burning what is written, only the medium or place of writing

Comment: That is not what I am asking..

Comment: What is written in the mushaf is the Qur'an, the speech of Allah

Comment: @Ghz.. ping....

Comment: "What is written in the mushaf is the Qur'an, the speech of Allah".. So, when a non-Muslim burns a Quranic Mushaf, he burns the eternal and uncreated speech of Allah? Yes or No? (Sorry if it is getting circular but I am just trying to understand your reasoning)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128279/discussion-between-the-z-and-ghz).