# A Question about Quran is created/uncreated

Tags: islamic-philosophy, aqidah

As discussed [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/63358/is-the-quran-uncreated-majority-opinion) and in many other discussions:

1 - Quran is the eternal/uncreated word of God.

2 - And people actions are created.

3 - Now, Books which we read & the words which we speak are our actions which are created as **we just agreed in the 2nd point**, than how come the recitation of the Quran or the Quranic mushaf is the eternal word of God? **Like how do Muslims come to this conclusion logically**?

If our actions are created and yet, what we recite or what we read is the eternal word of God, how is it different to an Atheist believing the Universe came from nothing or a Christian believing 3=1 ??

And finally, is there a Quranic verse or an authentic Hadith or a saying of a "Sahabi" about this matter? Is there an authentic Hadith or Quranic verse which says this question i.e "created/uncreated" is one of the questions that will be asked in grave or on the day of Judgement?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

To give a simple example, let us say you pick up the book Bidayah wan-Nihayah written by Ibn Kathir (RA) in around the year 1370 AD.

If you open it and read it aloud, the sound you make just came to exist in 2021. However, the words you are reading are from 1370 AD.

Keeping that example in mind, when you pick up a mushaf and recite the Quran, your sound was created, but what you are reciting (i.e. the recitation) is the uncreated word of God.

Comment: Ibn Kathir analogy is not sound as he was a Human.. A Christian can give an analogy of a Tree having a root, a trunk, and a branches yet it is all one or water being in 3 states i.e Liquid, vapor, and solid yet it is all one or an egg being composed of shell, white, and yolk yet it is all one or a triangle made-up of 3 angels yet it is all one... We are talking about God's eternal & uncreated word originating from created beings..  Is there any Hadith, Quranic verse, or any "Sahabi" quote about this matter?